# Why there is no output when I run dolphindb on command line?

Tags: database, data-analysis, dolphindb

I run dolphindb on windows command line and executed some scripts, but there is no output.

[image]

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command line, please type semicolon (;) as the end of the script.